# Registration method with Identity on an empty project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I'm working in an *empty MVC entity framework with ASP.NET Identity project*, trying to finish a `Register` method for an `IdentityController` that handle all *user related* operations.

The problem is that when trying to login with `SignInAsync` method after creating the user, the system doesn't find the references to work with that method.

So, on the following code snippet...:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using WebApplication.Models;

namespace WebApplication.Controllers
{
    public class IdentityController : Controller
    {
        UserManager<IdentityUser> UserManager = new UserManager<IdentityUser>(new UserStore<IdentityUser>(new WebApplicationIdentityDbContext()));
        RoleManager<IdentityRole> RoleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(new WebApplicationIdentityDbContext()));

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Register()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel credential)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if ((await UserManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityUser { UserName = credential.Name }, credential.Password)).Succeeded)
                {
                    await SignInAsync(User, false);

                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "StartupController");
                }
            }
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

...what is missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because it's not a framework method. It's just something the team added to the generated `AccountController`. Here's the code from my `AccountController`. I've modified mine a bit, but I think this is what the original looked like:

```
private async Task SignInAsync(User user, bool isPersistent)
{
    AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
    var identity = await UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
    AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = isPersistent }, identity);
}
```

Comment: Oh, I see. Where `User user` can I place and `IdentityUser user`? Because I'm using `IdentityUser` due it fulfills the needs of my project. Also, isn't this [way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19489527/moving-mvc5-account-controller-code-to-separate-project?rq=1) simpler?

Comment: Yeah sorry. `User` is *my* user, so yeah, you'll need to change that to your class.

Comment: And what about the link? What do you think?

Comment: I've added the method you'd post, but now it's seems to be  missing the references for `SignOut()` and `SignIn()` methods. Any idea?