# AuthenticationManager references missing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

Following up [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21564260/registration-method-with-identity-on-an-empty-project/21564504#21564504) question, there are missing the references for the methods `SignOut()` and `SignIn()`:

```
private async Task SignInAsync(User user, bool isPersistent)
{
    AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
    var identity = await UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
    AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = isPersistent }, identity);
}
```

Do someone knows how to solve it?

Answer (score 10):

How did you define your *AuthenticationManager* property? Normally it should look like the following:

```
private IAuthenticationManager AuthenticationManager
{
  get
  {
    return HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
  }
}
```

With that you should be able to call the *SignOut* and *SignIn* methods.

Answer (score 3):

If you are calling outside the controller then AuthenticationManager should be defined in following way.

```
    private IAuthenticationManager AuthenticationManager
    {
        get
        {
            return HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

GetOwinContext() is an extension method that exists in Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.dll.

You have to add the Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb NuGet Package.

It is part of the System.Web namespace. So, please make sure that you include the System.Web in using section.

Answer (score 0):

You might have included the `System.Net` instead of `Microsoft.Owin.Security`. Both have the definitions for `AuthenticationManager` class.

Answer (score -1):

The methods should be defined in the Microsoft.Owin.Security namespace. Can you check if you Microsoft.Owin dll is correctly referenced in the project